# Multibyte value to Firebase

Tags: java, firebase

I need to store Multibyte strings like "áčšěž" in Firebase. When I use Javascript API - it works and String "áčšěž" is in Firebase. But when I try it in Java `ref.setValue("áčšěž");` It  don´t work. There is no error message but Firebase set my client as disconnected, but method onDisconnect is not triggered.

My servlet code is:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/server/*", "/set/*"})
 public class FbServlet extends HttpServlet {

        private final Firebase ref = new Firebase(FbRef.refD + "xx");

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            ref.child("first").setValue("work"); //this is the first time okey
            ref.child("nowork").setValue("áčšěž"); //this do not work and after this command firebase do not work
            ref.child("last").setValue("dontwork"); //this do not work 

        }

    }
```

I try it on WildFly 8 and Tomcat 7.0.41. I am using JDK 1.7, maven and Windows XP.

Then I try it push to Openshift (WildFly 8) and It works, but writes "?????". :(

So my question is whether there is way how to do that? (Escape string, or something like that)

Log:

```
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Raising events for /.info/authenticated
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Doing onDiff with changes: []
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/authenticated
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/authenticated
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/authenticated
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Raising events for /.info/connected
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Doing onDiff with changes: []
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/connected
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/connected
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/connected
17:00:16,375 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] Connection: conn_0 - Opening a connection
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] RepoOperation: set: /data/xx/first
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] DataOperation: set: /data/xx/first com.firebase.client.snapshot.StringNode@1a
565fb
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] Transaction: Aborting transactions for path: /data/xx/first. Affected: /data/
xx/first
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Raising events for /data/xx/first
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /data/xx/first
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] RepoOperation: set: /data/xx/nowork
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] DataOperation: set: /data/xx/nowork com.firebase.client.snapshot.StringNode@6
7ab84
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] Transaction: Aborting transactions for path: /data/xx/nowork. Affected: /data
/xx/nowork
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Raising events for /data/xx/nowork
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /data/xx/nowork
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
17:00:16,390 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] RepoOperation: set: /data/xx/last
17:00:16,406 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] DataOperation: set: /data/xx/last com.firebase.client.snapshot.StringNode@2d8
40a
17:00:16,406 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] Transaction: Aborting transactions for path: /data/xx/last. Affected: /data/x
x/last
17:00:16,406 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Raising events for /data/xx/last
17:00:16,406 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /data/xx/last
17:00:16,406 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
17:00:16,406 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] Connection: conn_0 - closing realtime connection
17:00:16,406 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] WebSocket: ws_0 - websocket is being closed
17:00:16,421 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect
17:00:16,421 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Raising events for /.info/connected
17:00:16,421 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/connected
17:00:16,421 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:16 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
17:00:17,937 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] WebSocket: ws_0 - websocket opened
17:00:17,937 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive
17:00:17,937 INFO  [stdout] (TubeSockReader-1) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DE
BUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"d":{"t":"r","d":"s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.c
om"},"t":"c"}
17:00:17,937 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44999
17:00:17,953 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] WebSocket: ws_0 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
17:00:17,953 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] WebSocket: ws_0 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {d={t=r, d=s-dal5-nss-2
3.firebaseio.com}, t=c}
17:00:17,953 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] Connection: conn_0 - Got control message: {t=r, d=s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.co
m}
17:00:17,953 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] Connection: conn_0 - Got a reset; killing connection to ttdmmoq.firebaseio.co
m; instead connecting to s-dal5-nss-23.firebaseio.com
17:00:17,953 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] WebSocket: ws_0 - had an error: com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketException: IO
Error
17:00:17,953 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] WebSocket: ws_0 - |IO Error|
17:00:17,953 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] WebSocket: ws_0 - closed
17:00:17,953 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] WebSocket: ws_0 - had an error: com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketException: IO
Exception
17:00:17,953 INFO  [stdout] (FirebaseWorker) Wed May 21 17:00:17 CEST 2014 [DEBU
G] WebSocket: ws_0 - |IO Exception|
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using and the platform you're running on? I was able to set the value above and then get it back via a ValueEventListener using the latest Java client and Java 1.7 on OS X.

Comment: thanks for the update, I'll take a look and see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: I'm still not able to reproduce this error. Is there an exception being thrown in the logs by any chance?

Can you add:
  
  Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);

to the beginning of your application and post the logging output?

Comment: @GregSoltis I update my post (add logging output). There is no an exception.

Comment: So far the best I've been able to find says that the console output is  behaving as expected for WinXP: http://www.coderanch.com/t/538165/java/java/Displaying-UniCode-characters


It looks like the winXP console doesn't handle unicode very well. Can you try sending the \u escaped version of the string and see if that behaves better?

Apologies for all of the trial and error, I don't have access to an XP machine myself.